# Solving system of differential equations $ D\,x+z=e^t ,(D-1)\,x+D\,y+D\,z=0 , x+2\,y+D\,z=e^t $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

**Solve the given system of differential equations by systematic elimination.**
\begin{cases} D\,x+z=e^t \\ (D-1)\,x+D\,y+D\,z=0 \\ x+2\,y+D\,z=e^t \end{cases}

---

**My process of solving:**
$$ y= \frac{(1-2D)\,}{(D+2)} \,z $$
$$ x=\frac{(D^2-3D)}{(D+2)(D+1)}\, z $$
However I wasn't able to do rest, the problems seems very interesting! This is my first time doing differential equation in $(x(t), y(t), z(t)) $ system. I appreciate the community to help me.

Comment: You can aslo differentiate when it's needed. thats what you didnt do....Differentiate and eliminate. For example, you can differentaite first eqation and so eliminate all the DZ in second and third equation. And focus on these two equations and solve.

Answer (score 1):

Extract $z(t)$ from the first equation and $y(t)$ from the third.

Plug all of that in the second equation; you should have an equation of third order in $x(t)$ with constant coefficients. It is simple to solve.